Non-linear feedback shift register with 2 taps, of which 1 negated
I was toying around with a "non-linear" variant of linear feedback shift registers (LFSR); the source code can be found here.  This "negated" feedback shift register (FSR) only uses $2$ taps; one of these gets inverted (negated), and then the ${\tt XOR}$ of the two bits is used as the new bit. (Shift and new bit insertion works as usual.)
Results: For the 16-bit setting, choosing taps 8 and 15 for the "negative" and the positive tap respectively produces $63,457$ of total $65,536$ possible 16-bit strings when starting from the constant 0-string with 16 bits. The same result is obtained for taps 6 and 15, and then for 12 and 15 we get $57,337$ rounds. For all the other tap settings, the procedure terminates very quickly.
Questions.

The constant $1$-string is never reached, no matter what combination is used for the 2 input taps. Why is this? And is this true for all other bit lengths, not  just 16?

Given a fixed register length $n$and starting from the constant 0-string, can always 2 taps be found such that the number of rounds is some "largish" proportion  of all $2^n$ possible register contents, like $90\%$?

Due to the non-linearity of the setting, does this non-linear feedback shift register offer some security advantages compared to LFSR?


(Not all questions need to be answered for acceptance of answer.)

Actually, there's nothing nonlinear about this construction - negation is perfectly linear.

Ok, what is an easy example of a non-linear bijection $f:{0,1}^n\to{0,1}^n$?

One simple nonlinear bijection would be $f(a, b, c) = b, c, a \oplus (b \wedge c)$

The idea of NLFSRs as stream generators is quite old. But they are not as well known as LFSRs. Sometimes the nonlinearity is via a filtering function of the LFSR state, but this setup is different, the feedback function is nonlinear. If you just have a product of two different terms in a sum, you have a nonlinear function.
Tor Helleseth has done extensive work on NLFSRs. Another name to look out for is Elena Dubrova. A lot of that work may be behind paywalls, but try IACR.
The following PhD thesis from University of Melbourne is good to have a look at in terms of a relatively gentle introduction.
The GRAIN family of ciphers use an NFLSR as part of their design. Its expression is quite long. And of course, not in the context of stream ciphers, but the AES Sbox map $x\mapsto x^{2^n-2}$ is a nonlinear bijection.
